# SendGrid Events are running multiple times

Tags: node.js, sendgrid

Sendgrid Events are running multiple times with same message ID ? After getting processed delivered and open it is again running the same events

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is possible with the SendGrid Event Webhook. They have multiple Event servers, and it's possible for more than 1 to get the same event. You should be de-duplicating against the `sg_event_id` field, which is globally unique.

Comment: When they push same events data twice also they are adding sg_event_id  unique so how can i check its is a new unique open event or existing one

Comment: @DanielMasih if it's a unique `sg_event_id`, it should be a unique event. If you think it's an identical event with a unique ID, you should submit a Support request. Make sure and note that detail.

Comment: Did you resolve this? I am getting two open events.